# Attaching package: ‘MASS’ The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’: Select

Tags: r

I get this message in R:

> Attaching package: ‘MASS’
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
>
> select

Comment: What is your question? The message is only for your information.

Comment: How can resolve this error message

Comment: As I said, it *isn’t* an error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning message, not an error message, saying that both packages have a function named `select`.  Whichever package was loaded last will take precedence over the one loaded first.  You can discover all the name conflicts among the packages currently loaded in your workspace using:

```
conflicts()
```

and you can find which loaded packages have defined a specific name using:

```
find("select")
```

To resolve the conflict you can do one of these:

**1) Order of library statements** If you want to use the dplyr `select` invoke the library statements in this order.

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
```

**2) exclude** Alternately use the exclude= argument.  This will load MASS without its `select` function so all references to `select` in your code will only find the dplyr `select`.  This has the advantage that it is explicit and does not give any warnings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS, exclude = "select")
```

dplyr also has name conflicts with `filter` and `lag` in the base of R so assuming we want the base versions to take precedence we could write:

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(MASS, exclude = "select")
```

**3) Specify package** Another thing you can do is specify which `select` you want in your code by referring to it like this:

```
dplyr::select
```

or

```
MASS::select
```

**4) Redefine** or define select to be the one you want:

```
select <- dplyr::select
```

**5) Alternate function** Another possibility is to not use the conflicting names at all.  In the case of `select` we could use `subset` from the base of R or `fselect` or `slt` from the collapse package.  These all result in the same output.

```
dplyr::select(BOD, Time)

subset(BOD, select = "Time")

library(collapse)
fselect(BOD, Time)

library(collapse)
slt(BOD, Time)
```

Comment: I keep seeing that you are avoiding using the proper Markdown formatting for enumerations. — Is this intentional? Take a look at my (overridden) edit, which renders your enumeration in Markdown formatting. Besides looking better (obviously somewhat subjective), using the proper formatting makes the text more machine readable, which helps people with assistive technologies.

Comment: The markdown causes long lines to overrun on the right hand side making it harder to read.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Are you referring to the fact that the lines are indented and thus there’s less space for them? Either way, *not* indenting the lines makes them harder to read, because readers need to actively scan where enumeration items start and end. Either way, personally I’d prefer if you didn’t actively sabotage the unified (and consciously designed) formatting on this site, it massively detracts from your otherwise excellent answers.

Comment: My view is that clarity of the code takes precedence and using bold numbers is not harder to read than indentation.